# How to display short date in input field?

Tags: angularjs

I use [Angular JS Calendar](https://mattlewis.me/angular-bootstrap-calendar/).
There is input field with current date:

```
 <input
        type="text"
        class="form-control"
        readonly
        datepicker-popup="dd MMMM yyyy"
        ng-model="event.startsAt"
        is-open="event.startOpen"
        close-text="Close" >
```

By default it look as full date with day of week, time and day.

How I can set short date in this input field like as:

```
05 October 22:30
```

Comment: you can use moment js for formatting date

Comment: can you made fiddle or plunker ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if it is based on [angualr-ui bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) then changing the date format to ' MMMM dd HH:mm' should work like this .

```
<input
        type="text"
        class="form-control"
        readonly
        datepicker-popup="MMMM dd HH:mm"
        ng-model="event.startsAt"
        is-open="event.startOpen"
        close-text="Close" >
```

Let me know if this works for you.

I made a [sample plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/GZDacegf0nda7pLY5e1x?p=preview) to address your problem using [angular bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/)  .

Comment: which calendar you are using ? which version ?

Comment: check plunker sample . it is what you are looking for ?